# Leer datos de un archivo .srt

Tags: python

Estoy empezando en python y el el proyecto que tengo entre manos noe s muy complejo, pero hay alguna que otra dificultad.

Una parte del proyecto se bassa en abrir un archivo .srt y acceder a la información de un subtítulo a partir de su índice (entrada/salida y contenido). He estado mirando librerías y no logro dar con ninguna que me ofrezca este servicio o almenos que yo sepa (ni "pysrt" ni "srt" pueden hacerlo que haya visto)

Puede alguien ayudarme o decirme cómo tendría que hacerlo de manera alternativa? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un archivo .srt contiene subtitulos, cada uno de los cuales contiene:

```
numero_secuencia
tiempo_inicio --> tiempo_final
subtitulo linea 1
subtitulo linea 2
...
subtitulo linea n
<<linea en blanco>>
```

El tiempo_inicio y tiempo_final están en formato hh:mm:ss,mmm, y corresponden a tiempos desde el comienzo de la película.

Cada subtítulo contiene una o más líneas de texto que deben ser mostrados durante el tiempo indicado. Los subtítulos normalmente se limitan a una o dos línea, y se delimitan con una línea en blanco.

*Ejemplo*

```
1
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:07,000
Downloaded from
YTS.MX

2
00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:13,000
Official YIFY movies site:
YTS.MX

3
00:00:44,878 --> 00:00:46,713
LA FAMILIA PRIMERO #BENDECIDOS

4
00:00:46,796 --> 00:00:50,467
Todos queremos la familia perfecta,
pero ¿quién es perfecto?

5
00:00:50,550 --> 00:00:51,593
#UPS

6
00:00:51,676 --> 00:00:56,765
Toda familia tiene sus retos, desde el día
de la foto, hasta los líos para comer.

7
00:00:57,557 --> 00:00:59,976
Para mi familia, ¿el mayor reto?
```

**Proceso**

Este es un código simple que lee un .srt. Presupone un archivo bien formado, pues no tiene detección de errores.

El procedimiento es tomar la primera línea disponible como el número de secuencia; la siguiente línea, como los tiempos; y las lineas que sigan, como los subtítulos, hasta encontrar una línea vacía. Las líneas de subtitulos se guardan en una lista.

Obtenidos los datos, se imprimen y se reinicia el ciclo.

**Código**

```
with open("subtitle.srt", "r") as sub:
    while True:
        numero_secuencia = sub.readline().strip()
        if not numero_secuencia:
            break
        tiempos = sub.readline().strip()
        textos = []
        linea = sub.readline().strip()
        while linea:
            textos.append(linea)
            linea = sub.readline().strip()

        print(f"Secuencia: {numero_secuencia}")
        print(f"Tiempos: {tiempos}")
        print(f"Textos: {textos}")
```

produce:

```
Secuencia: 1
Tiempos: 00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:07,000
Textos: ['Downloaded from', 'YTS.MX']
Secuencia: 2
Tiempos: 00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:13,000
Textos: ['Official YIFY movies site:', 'YTS.MX']
Secuencia: 3
Tiempos: 00:00:44,878 --> 00:00:46,713
Textos: ['LA FAMILIA PRIMERO #BENDECIDOS']
Secuencia: 4
Tiempos: 00:00:46,796 --> 00:00:50,467
Textos: ['Todos queremos la familia perfecta,', 'pero ¿quién es perfecto?']
Secuencia: 5
Tiempos: 00:00:50,550 --> 00:00:51,593
Textos: ['#UPS']
Secuencia: 6
Tiempos: 00:00:51,676 --> 00:00:56,765
Textos: ['Toda familia tiene sus retos, desde el día', 'de la foto, hasta los líos para comer.']
```